# Play framework inherit dependency injected trait?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to create an overloaded `play.api.mvc.Controller` trait that has dependency injected arguments?

For example, say I have a couple of customized Actions that require a dependency injected AuthorizationService. I would like to write my controllers like this:

```
class UserController extends CustomController {
  def getUser(userID: String) = CustomAction {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to create the CustomController trait such that it doesn't require me to inject my AuthorizationService in my UserController. Is there a way to do this with Guice?

Answer (score 5):

You can inject a field into your **CustomController** trait. The field should'n be final so it has to be declared as **var** in Scala.

```
@Inject() var authService: AuthorizationService
```

You can also make the injected **var** private and declare a public **val** which references the injected field. In this case **val** has to be **lazy** since injection occurs after class was instantiated. See [Guice docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#field-injection) for more details.

```
@Inject() private var as: AuthorizationService = _
lazy val authService: AuthorizationService = as
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to inject a dependency into a trait because a trait isn't instantiable. A trait doesn't have a constructor to define the dependencies, you must inject your AuthService via UserController

Example.

```
trait CustomController extends Controller {
  val authService: AuthService
  ...
}

class UserController @Inject()(override val authService: AuthService) extends CustomController {
  ...
}
```